# print to the console all the items in the ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have declared an ArrayList of a generic string array

```
ArrayList<String[]> dataListCol = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

I am populating the arraylist this way

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String[] strArrayCol = new String[2];
                        strArrayCol[0] = json_data.getString("col1");
                        strArrayCol[1] = json_data.getString("col2");
                        dataListCol.add(strArrayCol);

                       }
```

I am attempting to print all the individual items in the array as shown

```
System.out.println("new array " + Arrays.toString(dataListCol.toArray()));
```

the output is not a meaningful string representation. Please how can I print all the items in the array

Comment: You need to call `Arrays.toString` on each element of your list: `dataListCol.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: `System.out.println("new array " + Arrays.deepToString(dataListCol.toArray()));` ?

Answer (score 2):

As each element itself is an `array`, you need to call `Arrays.toString` on each element to print the values, e.g.:

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.stream()
.map(Arrays::toString)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or, to print just one element, simply use the following inside the loop:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArrayCol));
```

**Update**

If you want to assign the `String` to a reference instead of printing it then you can use `Collector`, e.g.:

```
String string = list.stream()
.map(Arrays::toString)
.collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

This will give you pipe separated string for all the elements.

Comment: where are u getting this variable from (strArrayCol)

Comment: dont get what is happening here can u assign it to a variable >>>> 
list.stream()
.map(Arrays::toString)
.forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: Yes, you can, by using a `collector`. Do you want one string for the whole list?

Answer (score 0):

Two way to do that, loop or foreach method.

```
for (String object: list) {
  System.out.println(object);
}
```

or

```
ArrayList l=new ArrayList();
l.add(value);
l.forEach((a)->System.out.println(a));
```

hope that help you

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you are calling the method `tostring()` on the array that use the method for generic objects showing to you the hash of that specific object.

You can simply do something like this

```
    int size = t.length; 
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) { System.out.println(t[i]); 
}
```

Or in a simpler way you can use

```
Arrays.toString()
```

And

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

### What's Actually Happening

You've made a list that **`holds type String[]`**, when you ask the list to return to you it's state represented by an array, the call to `toArray()`, it returns an array that contains each element in the list.

So the array you've received back is an `Object[]` that contains all the elements in the list. Remember what type of elements you declared the list to hold -
 `String[]`

`Arrays.toString(Object[] array)` iterates through the array given calling `toString()` on each element. The runtime type of each element in the array you gave is `String[]`, therefore on every iteration `toString()` is being called on an array.

### What You Want to Happen

You want to call `toString()` on each **String** element in each **array of String** that the list is holding:

```
for(String[] strArray : dataListCol) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
}
```

or if your a fan of *spaghetti output*:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(dataListCol.toArray()));
```

**Note** `Arrays.deepToString(dataListCol.toArray()))` does what you wanted. This is because when focusing only on how elements are stored, essentially a `List<Object[]>` is equivalent to a 2D array, `Object[][]`, just as a `List<Object>` is equivalent to a single dimension array `Object[]`.

Except elements of an array are stored contiguously in memory whereas Collection classes do not store their elements contiguously (just to keep the memory heroes off my back)